# Retrieving Values From Nested HashMap from user input

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to retrieve values from a nested hashmap depending on user selection. I'm having trouble getting the values from the nested Hashmap.

I've created the HashMap like this

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> contentTypesMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

If the user selects MDX i want to go to the nested HashMap and get the two string values in the 2nd hashmap.

```
contentTypesMap.put("MDX", new HashMap<String,String>()).put("HELLO1", "FOO");
```

And this my function for where to use hashmap,

```
public void getDatabaseSelectionValues (){
  resourceType = (String) FileUtilityScreen.contentTypes.getSelectedItem();
  sqlTableName = contentTypesMap.get(resourceType).get(key);
  languageSelected = FileUtilityScreen.languagesFromDataBase.get(
  FileUtilityScreen.languageDropDown.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Comment: `HashMap#put`  returns ==>> "the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)"

Answer (score 0):

with your exemple, if the selection is "MDX", you get your second map by doing 
`HashMap<String,String> selection = contentTypesMap.get("MDX")`

then you can use entrySet() method to retrieve all entries of your map and iterate over entries.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HELLO1 and FOO meant to be the value for MDX?

You are not putting it correct. Try this:

```
Map<String, String> value = new HashMap<String, String>();
value.put("HELLO1", "FOO");
contentTypesMap.put("MDX", value);
```

I'd also consider wrapping this outer map in its own object as it may get complex.

Comment: Yes using Hell1 and FOO as dummy data for the HashMap, could you clarify about wrapping the outer map in its own object please

Comment: @Chris put method returns a String so you cannot use that with Map of type<String,HashMap<String,String>>

Comment: Oh yeah, I feel daft for putting that. The first of the two things I posted should work though. Will edit it now.

Comment: @furquanahmad This came to mind because I got told the same thing in a code review recently. Wrapping it gives more info about what the maps hold and is a good idea if you have a collection within a collection like this is what I was told. What is it exactly that you are storing in the maps? Can you post some dummy data thats similar to the actual data? I'll see if I can come up with an example then.

Comment: I'll be storing Table Names and column data for a DB. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation from Map.put(K key, V value)

> @return the previous value associated with key, or
>        null if there was no mapping for key

So calling `contentTypesMap.put("MDX", new HashMap<String,String>())` will always return the value that is not in the `contentTypesMap` map anymore.

Solution :

```
HashMap<String, String> map = contentTypesMap.get("MDX"); 
if (map == null) {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    contentTypesMap.put("MDX", map);
}
map.put("HELLO1", "FOO");
```

Or you can use guava Multimap instead.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant by a wrapper class in my comment above was something along these lines, to make it more readable. I'm assuming the key in the outer map is the table name, and in the inner map is the column name and data type for that column.

```
public class DatabaseTables {

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dbTables = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    public void addColumn(String tableName, String column, String type){
        Map<String, String> columns = dbTables.get(tableName);

        if(dbTables.get(tableName) == null) {
            columns = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        columns.put(column, type);
        dbTables.put(tableName, columns);
    }

    public Map<String,String> getColumnsForTable(String tableName){
        return dbTables.get(tableName);
    }
}
```

That still feels ugly though. I think a better solution than this, would be to have a class called Table, with a string property for the table name, and a map for its columns and data types.

And then, elsewhere, you could have a list or a set of type Table.

Edit: Or, in Table.java, rather than a map for the columns, you could have a list or set of type Column. And then create a column class with two fields, one for the column name and the other for the type.